# Replace ActionBar tab title by drawable (specific code)

Tags: android, android-actionbar

In my Android app, I want to replace the title of the ActionBar Tabs by drawables. How can I do that in my specific code? Here it is:

```
private String[] tabs = { "ConnectMe", "Andere" };

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R

          .layout.activity_main);

    // Initilization
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionBar = getActionBar();
    mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setStackedBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(getResources().getColor(R.color.ConnectMe)));
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);        

    // Adding Tabs
    for (String tab_name : tabs) {
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(tab_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: means you want to show image instead of text?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean @yakhtarali

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to create an xml file. if you have already created it, then try like this. Do inform me if it didn't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >


    <!-- Help -->
    <item android:id="@+id/ConnectMe"
          android:icon="@drawable/ConnectMe"
          android:title=""
          android:showAsAction="always"/>


</menu>
```

For reference check these links [Android Working with Action Bar](http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-working-with-action-bar/)

[Using the Android action bar (ActionBar) - Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidActionBar/article.html)

Comment: Is this based on the Proposition of Abd or is it to replace by the original code?

Comment: what does that mean? pardon me I didn't get it

Comment: Yes, sorry. Um, I tried replacing the "Web" entry with R.id.ConnectMe and then I got an error. Android Studio replaced it with String.valueOf(R.id.ConnectMe). Then I launched the app and there only was a Long number. So there's something which isn't working.

Comment: Do you know what I have to do there?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like changing the icons in the `onPrepareOptionMenu` as following:

```
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
MenuItem switchButton = menu.findItem(R.id.SwitchSearchOption);     
if(....Condition....){
    switchButton.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon1);
}else{
    switchButton.setIcon(R.drawable.menu_icon2);
}
return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try that. What do I have to replace SwitchSearchOption with?

Comment: write "onPrepar" in the main activity or fragment then click on `CTRL` + `SPACE` buttons and it should be auto completed

Comment: Ok, but at Condition I get an Expression expected error.

Comment: here `Condition` means you have to put your condition here